# Proving that there exists an equivalence relation that corresponds to a partition $P$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $X$ is a set, and $P$ is a partition of $X$.

**Prop:** There exists an equivalence relation $\sim$ in $X$ that corresponds to $P$.

**Pf:** Assume that $P = \{U_i\}_{i\in I}$, where $|I|<\infty$. Further assume that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation in $X$ such that for every $x, y\in X$, $x\sim y$ if and only if $x, y\in U_j$ for some $j\in I$.  Then for every $x\in X$, there exists some $U_j\in \{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that $x\in U_j$, and so, $x\in [x]\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in X}[x]$. Conversely, if $y\in [x]\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in X}[x]$, then $y\in U_j\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$, leading us to the fact that two partitions are equal.

Did I prove the assertion correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption $|I|<\infty$ is not part or, nor is implied by, the statement that you are trying to prove. The rest of the argument didn't prove the proposition either. You defined the right $\sim$. What you need to do is verify that it satisfies [the definition of equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition).

For example

Reflexivity: Since $x\in U_i\implies x\in U_i$, then $x\sim x$.

Symmetry: $x \sim y$ is equivalent to the existence of $U_i$ such that $x\in U_i$ and $y\in U_i$. This is equivalent to $y\in U_i$ and $x\in U_i$, which is equivalent to $y\sim x$.

Do transitivity next.